# App with fist, last, next and previous buttons

Tags: sqlite

NewBee here.  I am looking for a tutorial, article or sample code that details using first, last, next and previous buttons to display records from an SQLite database.  Thanks in advance for your help, Jim

Comment: I dread to think what the 'fist' button does.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses of `SELECT`:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

All you need to do to build your pager device is to do a SELECT limiting to, say, 20 results, and supply an offset which is (page - 1) * 20. Your previous/next will decrement/increment your page number, and your first/last will set page to 1 or its maximum value respectively.